# Assign value to variable in Java with Switch Stament

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to assign value to variable based on case with old Switch case it is not allowing is there any way or should i need to write initialize variable in each single case?

```
public static void printNumberInWord(int number){
        String inWord = switch(number){
            case 0 -> "ZERO";

            case 1: "ONE";
            break;
            case 2: "TWO";
            break;
            case 3: "THREE";
            case 4: "FOUR";
            case 5: "FIVE";
            case 6: "SIX";
            case 7: "SEVEN";
            case 8: "EIGHT";
            case 9: "NINE";
            default : "no Value"

        };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJDcK.png)

Enchanced Switch is working though as shown in **Case0**

Comment: Are you asking how to return a value from a `switch` statement? Your Question is not clear. Edit for clarity.

Comment: Of course, if you're really doing that, it would be a lot better to do: `String[] values = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE" };` and address only that range

Answer (score 2):

## Switch Expressions

In Java 14+, use switch expressions to return a value. See [*JEP 361: Switch Expressions*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361).

```java
int number = 7;
String word =
        switch ( number )
        {
            case 0 -> "ZERO";
            case 1 -> "ONE";
            case 2 -> "TWO";
            case 3 -> "THREE";
            case 4 -> "FOUR";
            case 5 -> "FIVE";
            case 6 -> "SIX";
            case 7 -> "SEVEN";
            case 8 -> "EIGHT";
            case 9 -> "NINE";
            default -> "N/A";
        };
```

> word = SEVEN

---

As another example, move that `switch` into a method.

```java
private static String digitToWord ( final int x )
{
    return
            switch ( x )
            {
                case 0 -> "ZERO";
                case 1 -> "ONE";
                case 2 -> "TWO";
                case 3 -> "THREE";
                case 4 -> "FOUR";
                case 5 -> "FIVE";
                case 6 -> "SIX";
                case 7 -> "SEVEN";
                case 8 -> "EIGHT";
                case 9 -> "NINE";
                default -> "N/A";
            };
}
```

Exercise that method:

```java
IntStream
.rangeClosed ( 0 , 10 )
.forEach ( 
    ( int i ) -> System.out.println ( i + " = " + digitToWord ( i ) ) 
);
```

Output:

```
0 = ZERO
1 = ONE
2 = TWO
3 = THREE
4 = FOUR
5 = FIVE
6 = SIX
7 = SEVEN
8 = EIGHT
9 = NINE
10 = N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the older switch statements (not switch expressions). You would use the `yield` keyword to return the result as the value of the switch statement.

```
int number = 1;
        String inWord = switch(number){
            case 1: yield "ONE";
            case 2: yield "TWO";
            case 3: yield "THREE";
            case 4: yield "FOUR";
            case 5: yield "FIVE";
            case 6: yield "SIX";
            case 7: yield "SEVEN";
            case 8: yield "EIGHT";
            case 9: yield "NINE";
            default : yield "no Value";

        };

        System.out.println(inWord);
```

Note that it does not use `break;` and that you cannot mix the two different types together (switch statements and switch expressions)